# Неправильно отображается сайт после изменения кодировки

Tags: php, кодировка

Разрабатываю собственную CMS систему, всё практически готово, но есть одно "но". Дело в том, что изначально система была написана в кодировке `cp1251`, а после переведена в `utf-8` (не только мета тег изменил, но и кодировку файлов).

На хостинге `ho.ua` система работает, однако кодировка на выходе `cp1251` и мы видим там кракозябры (уж так настроен веб сервер). На хостинге `1gb.ru` вообще пустая белая страница возвращается (показать, к сожалению, не могу). Вот [ссылка](http://t.pwon.pp.ua/laSearch/take_test/), как работает на домашнем компьютере.

Если есть время и возможность посмотреть систему, тыкнуть носом в ошибку или помочь с кодировкой, то прошу... Вот [ссылка](http://t.pwon.pp.ua/laSearch/cms_setup_v6.zip) на архив с системой, чтобы установить, нужно первым делом распаковать архив, а после установить права доступа **(0777)** для файла `install_master.php` и открыть файл `install_wizard.html` и следовать инструкциям установщика. И ещё парочка плагинов для неё:

1. [Опросы](http://t.pwon.pp.ua/laSearch/quick_polls.zip)
2. [Оценка страниц (rating)](http://t.pwon.pp.ua/laSearch/prating.zip)

Comment: Не, качать и разбираться лениво, чесслово. =) Возможные причины назвал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме мета-тэга и кодировки файлов часто приходится специально посылать заголовок с кодировкой

```
header("Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

Например, на мастерхосте без этой строчки автоматом отправляется 1251.
Еще надо проверить кодировку БД и, при необходимости, сделать запрос SET NAMES.

Comment: Заголовки отправлял, не помогло, подскажите текст запроса SET NAMES, и можно ли его добавить после строчек соединения с базой, или же ею заменить следующие?

    @mysql_query("SET character_set_client = $defaul_chars_4_base_connect");
    @mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = $defaul_chars_4_base_connect");
    @mysql_query("SET character_set_results = $defaul_chars_4_base_connect");
    @mysql_set_charset($defaul_chars_4_base_connect);

Comment: Выражение SET NAMES 'x' делает то же, что и три последовательных:   

    SET character_set_client = x;  
    SET character_set_results = x;  
    SET character_set_connection = x;  

Так что тут у вас все впорядке. А в какой кодировке отображается сайт?
Это можно проверить либо опытным путем, подбирая в браузере кодировку отображения, либо загнав в любой [декодер](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/)

Answer (score 4):

1. апач настроен на win-1251 (в .htaccess добавьте AddDefaultCharset utf-8)
2. БД в кодировке win-1251
3. В каком-то одном файле не поменяли кодировку.

Вроде все.